# Black blotches appear and quickly grow in camera view

Tags: camera

When in camera view a little blotch appears to the right of the render frame, and as soon as anything is done - selecting, moving, adjusting - it quickly grows and blots out the screen. Leaving camera view resets it.

[image: blender camera view blotches]

What causes that and how do I fix it?

[image]

[Screencast of how it behaves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRH22s2QW1o&feature=youtu.be)

A benchmark test with Unigine of the graphics card on my system, which is a Geforce GTX 960, went fine. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is very interesting, I've never seen anything like this before. Could you post blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: @LukeD Done. It is a little large - 26 Mb, but i figured i shouldn't change it.

Comment: Ok, everything is ok here. Tell me what GPU are you using, and is it overclocked?

Comment: @LukeD It is a GTX 960, no overclock. It has happened once or twice before recently and then the behaviour disappears for no reason i can find.

Comment: It's very strange, are you on Linux? Which driver version for GPU you have? I've checked in on Windows 10, I'm going to other PC to check it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this happen in just this one file, or all of them?

Comment: @LukeD Yes, i'm on the latest Ubuntu - 15.04 is it? It is using the Nvidia driver, version 361.42. I'll try to do a screencast so you can see how it develops.

Comment: 16.04 ;) Same OS, same drivers, GPU GTX 770 and everything still is ok. @SammySwanson asked important question. Turn off 'Depth of Field' in the right hand panel ('N' on keyboard) under 'Shading' tab.

Comment: It is just happening in this file right now. @LukeD Turning off Depth of Field did stop it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/yRH22s2QW1o

Comment: @SammySwanson I do remember it happened once before and it was likely another file, but one this was derived from. I think that time i messed around and found that turning of depth of field stopped it, and i decided to let it go.

Comment: It can be connected to grease pencil as it is only black object in this scene. Turning off depth of field is somewhat semi solution. Are you using any other GPU related software in the same time?

Comment: Just a bunch of browser tabs, nothing special.

Comment: Try running Unigine Benchmark. I'm really out of ideas but this looks like GPU memory error/glitch to me.

Comment: Okay, i'll run that and edit in anything that might be relevant. That'll be tomorrow though. Thanks.

Comment: Is AO enabled in the viewport?

Comment: @pycoder - Nope.

Comment: @LukeD I discovered i also left 2.76b on my system, it was installed with the Software Center. I removed it with the SC and also ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`. That caused a whole lot of stuff to be removed, cuz i never do maintenance. But this problem persists , in 2.77a in that specific file. An odd problem with [another file]*http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62063/7548) also persists, and also i can't append anything to any file. I have [asked about](http://askubuntu.com/q/819384/364597) removing config files. I don't know if that makes sense, but things are getting bad.

Comment: This is getting weirder. How Unigine Benchmark goes? Maybe try changing GPU drivers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Unigine Benchmark ran fine, overall score was 1174, there was some flickering in shadows in some scenes but it looked good otherwise. Thanks for the tip about drivers. According to Ubuntu the installed 361.42 driver is the recommended one, i had no idea the current version is now 367. I'll go through the steps it suggests.