# Does linking objects between files make it possible for all linked files to be corrupted?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

I have had a [couple of issues](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61997/7548) with [odd behaviour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62063/7548) in blender files recently, and it could well be due to file corruption. I am creating a file that includes objects from several files and wanted to make them linked. Then I thought - if something about my system is causing file corruption, am I risking all of those files becoming corrupted if the combined file is corrupted?

(I live in a place with a pretty shaky power grid that also has a lot of thunderstorms, so brown-outs and power outages are common. My computer is on a surge protector with a battery backup, but if that isn't the cause of these things, I don't know what else to check.)

Comment: Does all this happen only when the objects are linked, or does it happen also in the original files ? Just an idea with no real hope : do you have a render border defined somewhere ?

Comment: @lemon nothing has been linked up to now.

Comment: surely, not surprising : I have downloaded you file (previous question) and all is ok... but I have saved it and uploaded it to allow you to test [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1898" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1898/). If we (you) are lucky, that may disappear saved from another environment (?)

Comment: If the file is for some reason corrupted (in OS way) that won't work, but in this kind of situation, I try a dichotomous approach : remove half of your objects (or mesh parts). See if the problem is still there. If not reload and do the same with the other part. If yes, remove another half (quarter) etc. If this is one of the meshes that is the cause, that will allow to find it

Comment: Other idea : does it happen when with all rendering modes (wireframe, solid, etc.) ? In complement, If you try the dichotomous approach, remove the WindowFunnel first (an intuition)

Comment: @lemon no, i'm afraid it does that weird blotch thing on my machine still. Only that file, not any other i've found so far. It does it in solid, material, and texture, not in render or wireframe.

Comment: So the dichotomous approach could work to isolate the parts which cause that